# Icon is changing color after page refresh, not just after clicking, in Angular-ngrx app

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am trying to change color of mat-icon from grey to green when user clicks on it and update fields finished as true and set the date. Everything working normal in the background request is going to the service and states are updated on button click, but in the UI when i am refreshing the page then changes are reflecting. Where am I doing wrong?

```
`html`
<div class="reading-list-item" *ngFor="let b of readingList$ | async">
<button
    id="markAsFinish"
    class="tooltip"
    [attr.aria-label]="'Finish Reading'"
    mat-icon-button
    [style.color]="b.finished ? '#62c926' : 'grey'" 
    (click)="finishReading(b, b.bookId)"    
    >
      <mat-icon>{{ b.finished ? 'assignment_turned_in' : 'assignment_late' }}</mat-icon>
      <span class="tooltiptext">Finished Reading</span>
    </button>
```

```
`component.ts`
finishReading(item, id){
      this.store.dispatch(markBookAsFininshed({ item }))

  }
```

```
export const markBookAsFininshed = createAction(
  '[Books Search Results] Mark as finished after reading',
  props<{ item: ReadingListItem }>()
);
```

```
 on(ReadingListActions.markBookAsFininshed, (state, action) =>
    readingListAdapter.updateOne({ id: action.item.bookId, changes: action.item }, state)
  ),
```

```
updateFinishDate$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ReadingListActions.markBookAsFininshed),
      concatMap(({ item }) =>
        this.http.put(`/api/reading-list/${item.bookId}/finished`, item)
      )
    ),{dispatch: false}
  );
```

```
`service.ts`
 async markAsRead(id: string): Promise<void> {
      this.storage.update(list => {
        
        const index = list.findIndex(x => x.bookId === id);

        list[index].finished = true;
        list[index].finishedDate = new Date().toISOString();

        return list;
    });
```

```
@Put('/reading-list/:id/finished')
  async updateFinishedReadingList(@Param() params) {
    return await this.readingList.markAsRead(params.id);
  }**strong text**
```

Comment: Is a local storage or session storage handling involved? Maybe this is why the changed state of the list item is still the same after page refresh.

Comment: yes, local storage is used